# Spanning trees in planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Is the 3-connected graph(s) on $n$ vertices with the minimum number of spanning trees always planar?

Comment: I like this question, but I am wondering if you have any particular motivation for this.

Comment: This question came up when considering an old conjecture of Tutte 

"Among  all 3-connected  planar  graphs  with  2m  edges,  the  graph
with  the  smallest  number  of  spanning  trees  is  the  wheel  W(m+1)"

which is wrong. Then it became interesting to look at a more general version of this question.

Comment: This is a complete guess, but is the optimal graph a <a href=http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WheelGraph.html>Wheel graph</a>? The number of spanning trees is 16, 27, 45, 74, 121 ..., obeying the recursion $t_{n+1} = t_n+t_{n-1} + 2$. (That lists starts at 4 vertices, graphs with fewer than 4 vertices are never 3-connected.)

Comment: Sorry, cross posting. I see that my wrong guess has a prestigious history!

Comment: As stated in my previous comment, that is what Tutte conjectured, but this is wrong, and a counter example can be found at 30 edges. Take a path of length 2 and a path of length 12, then glue each vertex from the short path to each vertex of the long path. This graph is 3-connected, planar and has fewer vertices than the wheel-graph of the same size.

Comment: That paper I mentioned in the other post also completely classifies all minimal 3-connected graphs (of which these should be a subclass.)  They're all planer, so looks like a probable yes.

Comment: And of course I meant "fewer edges" instead of "fewer vertices" in my last comment.

Comment: It is not true that all minimal 3-connected graphs are planar, look for example at K3,3.

Comment: The "other post" that Gwyn mentioned seems to be http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42189/number-of-edges-in-low-complexity-graphs, and the paper is Fisher, Fraughnaugh, Langley, "P_3 connected graphs of minimal size".  Unfortunately, P_3 connectivity seems to be rather different from standard 3-connectivity.

Comment: Curiously, the sequence in David Speyer's 1st comment is given in Sloane http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A014739 with no reference to wheel graphs; rather, it is "Number of wedged $n$-spheres in the homotopy type of the Boolean complex of the affine Coxeter group $A_n$."

Comment: There may be something useful in Zbigniew R Bogdanowicz, Undirected simple connected graphs with minimum number of spanning trees, Discrete Math 309 (2009) 3074-3082. 

Comment: @utdiscant In case you haven't noticed the conjecture does not hold!

Answer (score 2):

Edit. As it turned out I was not using the right switch for *plantri*.

This is therefore not an answer anymore but rather an extended comment for the case $n=11.$

As it turns out the minimal number of spanning trees of a 3-connected planar graph of order 11 is 3965 and is attained by the graph on the figure bellow.

[alt text http://shrani.si/f/3f/IS/jiP8yvQ/pmin.png](http://shrani.si/f/3f/IS/jiP8yvQ/pmin.png)

As for the non-planar 3-connected graph I am yet to compute the answer. I'll post the result here as soon as it gets computed.

Comment: What about the following graph http://imgur.com/Eow3L6L which have 3965 spanning trees?

Comment: Weird. I'll try to run the program again and see why the proposed graph is not found. It clearly looks like a counterexample to the stated answer!

Comment: The image seems to be missing.